# Outputting odd and even number in array

Tags: php

Using below array, i'm trying to use foreach loop to iterate through each item. Then i need to apply if condition to check if the given number is even and odd. I also need to create two arrays one for even and one for odd and push each number in their respective category.

So i have done this so far:

These are the two arrays i created to push through the values to.

```
}

$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];

$array_odd = [];

$array_even = [];
 foreach ($numbers as $value)
{
 if (value %2 == 0)

 {
   $array_even = $value;
   echo $array_even;
}
else 
{    
$array_odd = $value;  
  echo $array_odd;
}
```

I'd like to know if i'm using the correct solution or are there major errors im committing?

Comment: If you want to save the $value to the respective arrays then you will need to use $array_even[] = $value; and $array_odd[] - $value;

Comment: You need to push the values into the array i.e. `$array_even[] = $value;`. Also note you can't `echo` an array, you need to `print_r` or `var_dump` or `var_export` it

Comment: You might find using [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) easier, `$array_even = array_filter($numbers, function ($v) { return $v % 2 == 0; });` and similar for `$array_odd`

Answer (score 0):

It will surely work like charms.

```
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];

$array_odd = [];

$array_even = [];
 foreach ($numbers as $value)
 {
  if ($value %2 == 0)
  {
    $array_even[] = $value;
  }
  else 
  {    
   $array_odd[] = $value;
  }
 }
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($array_odd);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($array_even);
```